# Developer Tools group to allow this

Tags: xcode, swift

I've working on xcode for swift programming.
When I tried to continue working on it today, it suddenly asked me

"___ needs to take control of another process for debugging to continue. Type the name and password of a user in the "Developer Tools" group to allow this"

when i tried to compile and to run my project on simulator.
I read similar posts that other people posted in StackExchange, and I tried DevToolsSecurity in terminal, but it replies Developer mode is already enabled.

I have no idea how to fix this, because it never happened to me last 9 months.

Note: I cannot use sudo in terminal. Also, I am not admin so my username and password are not working..

Comment: Did you try restarting the computer?

Comment: it just says "Developer mode is already enabled"

Comment: Yes I did... but nothing changed